# SonarQube community edition licensing

Tags: sonarqube, licensing

I need some clarifications about Sonarqube community edition licensing.

Editions comparison web page "http://www.sonarsource.com/products/editions/" say that the community edition is "Single Technology".

I'm not sure to really understand this. Does it means that on community edition I will not have right to install Java and C# plugin on a same instance of SonarQube server ?

Or perhaps I can do this, but will have restricted features in comparison of Enterprise Edition ?

Regards,
     Laurent.

Answer (score 2):

You can install all the community language plugins you like under the Community Edition. What this page is saying is that you're more likely to be successful running without support in small, simple environments, such as a mono-site, mono-language development environment.

Comment: Is there a total users limitation under the Community Edition? Today all our users can't login, and the default admin user can't even reset their password.

Comment: No limit. At a guess, you're using LDAP for authentication & should look at your LDAP configs.

Comment: Right, our problem was LDAP binding account expired.